# Missing the COM tab in Add Reference in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight

I am making a silverlight app that requires text to speech. I have found a ton of references on how to use the text to speech app but in order to use the library I need to add the COM component to the references. It says

"To create this, open the project in Visual Studio. Select the Project menu and click Add Reference. Select the COM tab, select "Microsoft Speech Object Library" in the list, and click OK."

The problem is that when I go to add reference there is no COM tab and I don't know how to get it. If someone could help that would be great

Comment: You can't add COM references to Silverlight projects can you?

Comment: Dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204381/silverlight-and-com-interop

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965613/can-i-use-activex-with-silverlight4

Comment: Yes but isn't there a silverlight COM interop feature?

Comment: Was it there at one point, or has it been gone since you installed VS?